# How to read data from SQL Server database using Data Set / Data Adapter?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to do a simple thing, display data from a table that is in a SQL Server database.

I used the Data Source tab to add a Data Set and configure the Data Adapter.

The structure in Data Sources tab looks like this :

```
MyDataSet
- MyTable
-- ColumnA
-- ColumnB
-- ColumnC
```

Now I would like to get all the values from `ColumnB` and write them to the console, basically `select ColumnB from MyTable`.

How do I do that using the Data Set / Data Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question, the below may help you:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in MyDataSet.Tables["MyTable"])
{
   Console.WriteLine(dr["ColumnB"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Close enough, your solution resulted in "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'". I had to use the adapter, it's working with DataRow dr in MyDataAdapter.GetData() in foreach statement. Thanks!